# Microsoft JET Database Engine error '80040e10' No value given for one or more required parameters

Tags: asp.net

I am currently a student attempting to learn and understand ASP. I would like to apologize in advance for any obvious or silly mistakes that might be discovered. I have no knowledge or understanding of ASP. I will be grateful for any advice or solution provided.

My assignment: To use access database (2003 version of access) to create a doctor's list, in order to search for the doctor by name and/or zip code. I have created the doctor's list "Contacts. mdb" in access (2003), the html page with the form to allow for the search based on name and/or zip code of the doctor and the ASP page in order to retrieve the results based on the search criteria.

The error I receive: 
SELECT * FROM contacts where lastname like '%%';
Microsoft JET Database Engine error '80040e10'

No value given for one or more required parameters.

/HPA563/Spring2014/kpatha3/Dynamic/OBGYNASPcode.asp, line 21

My html form code:

```
<html>
<body>

<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="OBGYNASPcode.asp">
  <label>Doctor's last name:
  <input type="text" name="searchTerm" />
  </label>
  <label>ZIP code:
  <input type="text" name="locationTerm" />
  </label>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
  </p>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

ASP Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>OBGYN ASP Page</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="white" text="black">
<%
Set adoCon = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

adoCon.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("contacts.mdb")

Set rsDoctors = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

if (request.form("locationTerm")="") then
   strSQL = "SELECT * FROM contacts where lastname like '%" & request.form("searchTerm") & "%';"
else
    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM contacts where lastname like '%" & request.form("searchTerm") & "%' and zipcode = " & request.form("locationTerm") &";"

end if
Response.Write strSQL

    rsDoctors.Open strSQL, adoCon   

Response.Write ("<table border='1' width='600'>") 
Response.Write ("<tr><td><b>Name</b></td><td><b>Location</b></td></tr>") 
Do While not rsDoctors.EOF 

Response.Write ("<tr><td>")
    Response.Write (rsDoctors("firstName") &"&nbsp;"& rsDoctors("lastName"))  
    Response.Write ("</td><td>") 
    Response.Write (rsDoctors("zipcode")) 
    Response.Write ("</td>") 

    rsDoctors.MoveNext 
    Loop

    rsDoctors.Close
    Set rsDoctors = Nothing
    Set adoCon = Nothing

%>

</body>
</html>
```

If I am missing any information, please let me know.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you enter something in the searchTerm field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*No value given for one or more required parameters.*

```
SELECT * FROM contacts where lastname like '%%'
                                            ^^-------- Missing parameter here.
```

I'm guessing that no search term was entered.

Comment: `strSQL = "SELECT * FROM contacts where lastname like '%" & request.form("searchTerm") & "%';"` -- I suspect `request.form("searchTerm")` is empty string.

Comment: Yes, that's what I said.

Comment: What, in that line of text below the code block? The one I didn't read? If you say so :)